# Using Perceptron sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier() gives an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, perceptron, adaboost

I have the problem of using perceptrons for AdaBoost classifier.

The training and testing data from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/poker/)
should be turned to 0 and 1 in the last column ("Poker Hand"), (it is from 1 to 9 inclusively originally), then both Decision Tree Classifier and AdaBoost Classifier with the total of 15 weak perceptron classifiers should be implemented in the data. I try to use **scikit-learn** libraries, but while my Decision Tree Classifier provides good results, AdaBoost Classifier throws error:

`ValueError: BaseClassifier in AdaBoostClassifier ensemble is worse than random, ensemble can not be fit.`

Here, the crucial parts of the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn import metrics

if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    data_train = pd.read_csv("poker-hand-testing.data",header=None)
    data_test = pd.read_csv("poker-hand-training-true.data",header=None)
    

    for value in range(0, len(data_train)):
        if data_train[10][value] != 0:
            data_train[10][value] = 1
    
    for value in range(0, len(data_test)):
        if data_test[10][value] != 0:
            data_test[10][value] = 1

    col=['Suit of card #1','Rank of card #1',
     'Suit of card #2','Rank of card #2',
     'Suit of card #3','Rank of card #3',
     'Suit of card #4','Rank of card #4',
     'Suit of card #5','Rank of card #5',
     'Poker Hand']
    
    data_train.columns=col
    data_test.columns=col
    
    y_train=data_train['Poker Hand']
    y_test=data_test['Poker Hand']
    
    x_train=data_train.drop('Poker Hand',axis=1)
    x_test=data_test.drop('Poker Hand',axis=1)
    
#The problematic part
    classifier = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=Perceptron(), n_estimators=15, algorithm='SAMME')
    classifier = classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
    
    print("Accuracy of AdaBoost:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The strange thing is that this error occurs only once per 9-10 times when I don't change values to binary ones, while binary values almost always gives an error. Also, changing `Perceptron()` to `SGDClassifier(loss="perceptron", eta0=1, learning_rate="constant", penalty=None)` also throws such errors.

My questions are:

1. What is the solution with the possibility of using **scikit-learn** library?
2. Is there any way to handle such an exception? For example, if it gives error, execute it again until desired results?
3. Are there any other alternatives where I can use both Decision Tree and AdaBoost with Perceptron, if it is couldn't be solved in **scikit-learn** library?

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part could be solved by try-catch block. For example,

```
#The problematic part solution
AdaBoost_accuracy = 0

while AdaBoost_accuracy == 0:
    try:
        classifier = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=Perceptron(), n_estimators=15, algorithm='SAMME')
        classifier = classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = classifier.predict(x_test)
        AdaBoost_accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    except:
        print("Let me reclassify AdaBoost again")

print("Accuracy of AdaBoost:", AdaBoost_accuracy)
```